# Python- Session Invalid during multiple class obj creation

Tags: python-3.x, api

I am trying to access the methods for multiple accounts, below is the code

```
accounts = {}
credentials = {'Orb1': {'uid': 'xx','pwd': 'xxxx'},
               'Orb2': {'uid': 'xx','pwd': 'xxx'}}

for Brok, creds in credentials.items():
    if Brok.startswith('Orb'):
        accounts[Brok] = Account(creds['uid'], creds['pwd'],'Orb')

print(accounts['Orb1'].Orbapi.get_limits()) # Session is expiring and getting invalid session error
print(accounts['Orb2'].Orbapi.get_limits())

class Account:
    def __init__(self, uid, pwd,brok):        
        if brok == 'Orb':                      
            class Api(KApi):
                def __init__(self):
                    KApi.__init__(self, host='xxx', websocket='xxx')                    
            self.Orbapi = Api()        
            self.result = self.Orbapi.login(userid=uid, password=pwd)
```

Note: when I try to print the accounts dictionary, I am getting below output
{'Orb1': <**main**.Account object at 0x0000021572329600>, 'Orb2':<**main**.Account object at 0x0000030255629600>}
even if I try to access the methods like accounts['Orb1'].get_limits() --> I am getting error No attribute found.

How can access to the methods for all accounts once they are validated.